# sql datatype for secretquestion checkbox in signup page

Tags: mysql

I have created form and after tat I created the sql table below I want to make sure that the data type I created are correct..help me
table

```
create table user_login (
 `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `emailid` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `password` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `retypepassword` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `gender` char(1) enum('m''f'),
 `secretquestion` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `answer` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `mobileno` char(10) check (mobileno<11)NOT NULL,
 `dob`DATE NOT NULL,
 `occupation` varchar(30) NOT NULL,                          
 `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `state` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `pincode` char(6) check (pincode<7)NOT NULL,
 `checkbox` tinyint(1),
 UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
```

and make sure that the data type for secret question is correct...

Comment: i think you need nvarchar(10) for ex in city somebody enters this `ಕನ್ನಡ` then when you do `select * from table` it'll be listed as ????

Answer (score 0):

It's looking good.

```
create table user_login (
     `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
     `emailid` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
     `password` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
     `retypepassword` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
     `gender` char(1) enum('m''f'),
     `secretquestion` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
     `answer` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
     `mobileno` char(10)NOT NULL,
     `dob`DATE NOT NULL,
     `occupation` varchar(30) NOT NULL,                          
     `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
     `state` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
     `pincode` char(6) NOT NULL,
     `checkbox` tinyint(1))
```